# I want to extract links of members

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I am trying to extract links of the following members

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
r = requests.get('https://www.aapkiawaz.in/about/doctor-hospital-directory-medical-directory-doctors-doctor-hospital-listing-medical-directory-doctors-listing-medical-directory-doctors-doctor-hospital-guide-medical-directory-d/0')
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text,'lxml')
##for link in soup.find('span',class_='person_name'):
for link1 in soup.find_all('span',class_='person_name' ):
   link2 = link1.find('a')
   print link2['href']
```

I am expecting the profile links of members but i am getting the following output:

```
{{project.mainbtnLink}}
```

Answer (score 4):

The page is using javascript to update content and you are seeing a placeholder essentially for those updates. You can mimic the POST request API call the page uses to get this content

```
import requests

data = {
    'type': 'social_data',
    'page' : 1,
    'size' : 50,
    'assigned_group' : 1061,
    'categoryid' : 1070
}

r = requests.post('https://www.aapkiawaz.in/api/social_data.php', data = data).json()
links = [item['mainbtnLink'] for item in r['rec']]
print(links)
```

---

Names as well:

```
info = [(item['data']['person_name'], item['mainbtnLink']) for item in r['rec']]
```

---

Unpack tuples into 2 lists:

```
names, links = zip(*[(item['data']['person_name'], item['mainbtnLink']) for item in r['rec']])
```

---

Dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd

info = [(item['data']['person_name'], item['mainbtnLink']) for item in r['rec']]
df = pd.DataFrame(info, columns = ['name' , 'link'])
print(df)
```

Comment: That's awesome. But I still wonder how to get the name of the person.